# self.driver.get_window_size() not returning dictionary with height or width

Tags: android, python, appium, appium-android

I'm having a problem on getting the size of the device with my Appium script. My plan is to make a function like the one below to get the screen size and then calculate the points which are used in the swipe operation.

```
size = self.driver.get_window_size()
start_y = size.height * 0.5
end_y = size.height * 0.5
start_x = size.width * 0.8
end_x = size.width * 0.2
self.driver.swipe(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, 400)
```

The problem I have with this code is that apparently it's not returning a dictionary with the height and width attributes. Error:

```
  File "/path/tests/AppiumTest.py", line 88, in swipe_right_to_left
start_x = size.width * 0.8
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'width'
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my fault. This would be the correct way on doing it:

```
start_y = size['height'] * 0.5
end_y = size['height'] * 0.5
start_x = size['width'] * 0.8
end_x = size['width'] * 0.2
```

So the correct way to get the values from size variable is `size['key']`, not `size.key`.